# Sleeping a worker thread in a file server

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I am implementing a file server and it receives requests from multiple clients. Each client sends multiple requests. At the server end, the main thread spawns a new worker thread to handle requests each time a new client connects. One worker thread handles all requests from the client it was created for. So, after the thread handles a requests, it waits to be woken up by the main thread when another request from the same client arrives.

I am not sure how to implement the last line.that is how do i put a thread to sleep and wake it again.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by threads created at the beginning of a client connect and thereafter the thread receives and sends messages directly to client rather then the main thread receiving and sending messages after the worker threads does the task.

Answer (score 0):

Use condition variables https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal

Answer (score 0):

You do not "put a thread to sleep".  A thread will sleep when it makes any blocking system call.

There are many ways to implement what you describe, the most common perhaps being the ["Thread pool pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).  This is usually implemented using a thread-safe queue, which in turn can be implemented with mutexes and condition variables.

The worker thread will go to sleep when it waits on the condition variable (pthread_cond_wait), and the master will wake it up by signaling the condition variable (pthread_cond_signal).

A little searching should turn up a number of pthread-based sample code for queues.

Answer (score 0):

You should study the problem of producers-consumers. In a nutshell you want to do something like this:

- Worker thread tries to **get** "job" from a queue
- If the queue is empty, **the thread blocks** (semaphore / condition variable), otherwise it gets the job and processes it
- The master queue **puts** jobs onto queues and **notifies workers** ("hey, there's work to do")
- A notified worker instantly wakes up and tries to **get** a job from the queue

The trick is to do it real elegant:

- the **get** should automatically
  **block** when the queue is empty
- the **put** should automatically
  **signal** workers waiting on it

How would you do this with what Linux puts at your disposal ?

- [sempahores](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)
- [pthreads condition variables](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Now, back to your question. It seems slightly dubious that you start a thread for each client. It would be *way* simpler if you could have a thread pool sitting around and processing requests from any client.

Comment: Starting a thread for each client is definitely *simpler*. It may be less efficient, but on modern implementations I doubt the difference is anywhere as big as you think it is.

Comment: @R.. You're probably right. Still, I find there's something unsettling about starting threads many times a second and letting them die. Again, with modern stuff (`clone` and such), starting threads for each client might be quite viable.

Comment: My casual testing shows `pthread_create` costs about the same as opening `/dev/null` 2-4 times. Of course that's not necessarily factoring in any possible cache/TLB impact, but if your application is largely IO-bound and/or syscall-bound anyway, it's unlikely to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Do your client-handling threads hold any state for the client?  If so, I can understand why you would need one, dedicated thread for each client.  If this is the case, you could use a producer-consumer queue for each client-handler thread as suggested by Cnicutar and other posters.  I usually use a semaphore togehter with a mutex since such synchro is available on all platforms, but condvars OK.  It is not clear how you identify the client when a file request comes in, so managing the client threads may be awkward, or not.  When a file request comes in to the main thread, how do you know which queue to push it on?

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score -1):

You have several possibilities, but I implemented a similar multithreaded solution as follows:

- Allow your worker thread's method to return when it has no work to do
- When your parent thread receives a request, add it to the worker thread's queue, and call a "Wakeup" method, along the lines of:

  ```
  private void Wakeup()
  {
      if (!_workerThread.IsBusy)
          _workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  ```

This will allow you to not have your thread hung in sleep state, where it would need to regularly check to see if a wakeup has been requested.  This puts the responsibility of waking  up the worker thread onto the parent thread.

Comment: Threads do not "hang" in sleep state.  And when they are in sleep state, they do not "regularly check to see if a wakeup has been requested".  Sleeping threads consume exactly zero CPU.